# How to reset index on pandas dataframe inserting resulting column on a specific position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How to keep columns order after operations on index?

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [0,1], 'b' : [0,1], 'c' : [0,1]})
>>> df.columns
Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
>>> df = df.set_index('c')
# some filtering operation
>>> df = df.reset_index()
>>> df.columns
Index(['c', 'a', 'b'], dtype='object')
```

After resetting index the order of columns is ['c', 'a', 'b'] instead of previous ['a','b','c']
Is there a way to reset_index with specifying where I want to insert the column?

I know I can use `pd.reindex(column_names)` but I wonder if there is a faster way to do this

This would come in handy, as I often use some column as index when I intend to perform filtering on said column, and need to reset index before writing results to a .csv file. The order of columns is fixed.

Comment: Can you change to filtering on the columns that way you don't go through the index manipulation?

Comment: Like
`df.loc[df['a'].isin(a_filtered_series)]` ?
I usually end up doing this, but I find 
`df.loc[a_filtered_series]` more handy (assuming a is an index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to store the original order columns in a variable and later use that variable to assign after resetting index. Have a look in the below code.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [0,1], 'b' : [0,1], 'c' : [0,1]})
print('Before reset index:', df.columns)

col = df.columns   # assign columns

df = df.set_index('c')
df = df.reset_index()

# get same order columns
df = df[col]
print('\nAfter reset index:', df.columns)
```

Refer to the below snapshot for the output.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also simply not drop the columns when setting as index, and then dropping them when re setting the index:

```
df = df.set_index('c', drop=False)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```